# VB.NET Copy a file name to the clipboard that can be pasted to mail or word as a hyperlink

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

I would like to create a hyperlink from a known file name and path and put it on to the notepad as a hyperlink that can be pasted to a word document or mail etc. that when clicked on will open the associated file.
I realize this will only work within the same network where the file is shared.

basically I want to be able to paste 
(A href="File:///C:\MyFILE.txt")myfile.txt(a) 
in to the clipboard in an html format...  so it will appear as a hyperlink when pasted into word or an email.
ie  Clipboard.SetText("File:///" & filepath, TextDataFormat.Html)

Any ideas?  I am having no luck

Thanks

Comment: This seems rather useless.  This kind of link would only work on the *computer* it was copied from, not the *network* - unless it used a UNC path instead of a drive letter path.

Comment: You have a couple of better options.  `1.` just attach the file in question to the email/word doc.  `2.` Set up a real file server, place the files in there, and create links to those files.

Comment: No this would work quite nicely in a domain where we use such links all the time...  And hence the reason I am trying to get it to work.  However it is not the content that is the issue it is getting the clipboard to accept an html link that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do it like this:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21966855/Create-a-hyperlink-in-VB-net-copy-to-clipboard-Should-be-able-to-paste-hyperlink-in-Microsoft-Word-Excel.html

It doesn't seem like the cleanest method. but it does work

Comment: Answers that are link-only are bad form for SO and generally removed.  Please read the SO FAQ, and then add the relevant solution information so that it will be useful to other people.